# How to add numbers in nested Python lists

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have a list

```
[["Sunday", 7, 0], ["Sunday", 2, 0], ["Monday", 1, 5], ["Tuesday", 5, 0], ["Thursday", 2, 0], ["Friday", 3, 0], ["Friday", 1, 0], ["Saturday", 4, 0], ["Monday", 8, 0], ["Monday", 1, 0], ["Tuesday", 1, 0], ["Tuesday", 2, 0], ["Wednesday", 0, 5]]
```

Can I add the values in the lists to get sums like

```
["I dont need this value", 37, 10]
```

Comment: I presume the `100` and the `60` are just some arbitrary examples, and not the actual results you expects for the list in your question?

Comment: Yes those are arbitrary numbers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is precisely what [`reduce()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reduce) is made for:

```
In [4]: reduce(lambda x,y:['',x[1]+y[1],x[2]+y[2]], l)
Out[4]: ['', 37, 10]
```

where `l` is your list.

This traverses the list just once, and naturally lends itself to having different -- possibly more complicated -- expressions for computing the three terms.

Comment: Please if you don't mind i want to ask one more question to you, either on chat or anything

Comment: Why not ask your question here so everybody can participate?

Answer (score 5):

For a flexible number of values per item and even less characters, you can use

```
In [1]: [sum(values) for values in zip(*l)[1:]]
Out[1]: [37, 10]
```

`zip` yields tuples of combinations of corresponding items (i.e. a tuple with all the 1st items, a tuple with all the 2nd items, etc), which can be summed up each (except for the first string value). Of course, you can still prepend `""` or whatever you like at the beginning if needed.

Answer (score 4):

I assign your list to `l`:

```
l = [ your list .... ]
['dont needed', sum( [ x[1] for x in l ] ), sum(  [x[2] for x in l ] ) ]
```

Result:

```
['dont needed', 37, 10]
```

Answer (score 4):

of course, the ultimate:

```
>>> stuff=[["Sunday", 7, 0], ["Sunday", 2, 0], ["Monday", 1, 5], ["Tuesday", 5, 0], ["Thursday", 2, 0], ["Friday", 3, 0], ["Friday", 1, 0], ["Saturday", 4, 0], ["Monday", 8, 0], ["Monday", 1, 0], ["Tuesday", 1, 0], ["Tuesday", 2, 0], ["Wednesday", 0, 5]]
>>> stuff=zip(*stuff)
>>> map(sum,stuff[1:])
[37, 10]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> stuff=[["Sunday", 7, 0], ["Sunday", 2, 0], ["Monday", 1, 5], ["Tuesday", 5, 0], ["Thursday", 2, 0], ["Friday", 3, 0], ["Friday", 1, 0], ["Saturday", 4, 0], ["Monday", 8, 0], ["Monday", 1, 0], ["Tuesday", 1, 0], ["Tuesday", 2, 0], ["Wednesday", 0, 5]]
>>> sum(j for i,j,k in stuff),sum(k for i,j,k in stuff)
(37, 10)
```